# Autowired Field is Null

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Im have been working on a example for spring MVC + Spring Security + hibernate to make a login page, but now i have come to a problem with a fuel `@Autowire` that keeps giving me null values. the server doesnt report any errors its just that it doesnt complete the operation.

CustomUSerDetailsService.java

```
package com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.dao.UsuarioDao;
import com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.model.Usuario;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired UsuarioDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        logger.info(username);
        Usuario domainUser = userDao.getUsuario(username);
        logger.info(domainUser.getUsername());

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(
            domainUser.getUsername(),
            domainUser.getPassword(),
            enabled,
            accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(domainUser.getRol().getId()));
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer rol){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(rol));
        return authList;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(Integer rol){
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(rol.intValue() == 1){
            roles.add("ROLE_DOCTOR");
            roles.add("ROLE_ASISTENTE");
        }else if (rol.intValue() == 2){
            roles.add("ROLE_ASISTENTE");
        }
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;

    }

}
```

Here the field `userDao` keeps beign null so when i try to use `userDao.getUsuario(username)` the operation just doesnt continue, it doesn't report an error or similar its just gives me a 404- error

UsuarioDao.xml

```
package com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.model.Usuario;

@Repository
public class UsuarioDaoImp implements UsuarioDao {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsuarioDaoImp.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario getUsuario(String username) {
        logger.debug("probando");
        List<Usuario> userList = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Usuario u where u.Username = :username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        userList = query.list();
        if (userList.size() > 0){
            return (Usuario) userList.get(0);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Enable transaction Manager -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- DataSource JNDI -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/paidos" resource-ref="true" />

    <!--  Session factory -->
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" 
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
        p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties"
        p:packagesToScan="com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.model" />

    <!--  Hibernate Properties -->
    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        </beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
    </util:properties>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.carloscortina.paidosSimple" />

</beans:beans>
```

I dont know whats missing , so any idea its welcome, thanks in advance.

Edit:
UsuarioDaoImp

```
package com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.model.Usuario;

@Repository
public class UsuarioDaoImp implements UsuarioDao {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsuarioDaoImp.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario getUsuario(String username) {
        logger.debug("probando");
        List<Usuario> userList = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Usuario u where u.Username = :username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        userList = query.list();
        if (userList.size() > 0){
            return (Usuario) userList.get(0);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

After trying to add a bean with UsuarioDaoImp i got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioServicioImp': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.dao.UsuarioDao com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.service.UsuarioServicioImp.usuarioDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.dao.UsuarioDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: usuarioDaoImp,userDao
```

UsuarioServiceImp

```
package com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.dao.UsuarioDao;
import com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.model.Usuario;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UsuarioServicioImp implements UsuarioService{

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioDao usuarioDao;

    @Override
    public Usuario getUsuario(String username) {
        return usuarioDao.getUsuario(username);
    }

}
```

i think I'm short in knowledge about the subject, that why i was following an example but i ended with this, so my apologise if I'm not giving the information correctly or if im misunderstanding  concepts.

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <beans:bean class="com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.service.CustomUserDetailsService" id="customUserDetailsService"></beans:bean>

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/sec/moderation.html" access="ROLE_ASISTENTE" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_DOCTOR" />   
        <security:form-login login-page="/user-login.html" 
            default-target-url="/success-login.html" 
            authentication-failure-url="/error-login.html" />  
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/index.html" />
    </security:http>  

    <security:authentication-manager>  
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">  
            <security:password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </security:authentication-provider>  
    </security:authentication-manager>  

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Where did you create the UsuarioDaoImp bean?

Comment: well itought that it was wire by spring using the annotation @@Repository on the UsuarioDaoImp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you accessing CustomUSerDetailsService class ? I hope you haven't added this class as bean in security config file or any other spring config?

**Editted:**
Your service bean is annotated with @service and you have also declared it in xml, spring has created two service beans one based on @service annotation (fully populated as its autowried) and second using the xml config (in which I assume you haven't injected dao dependency explicitly), so the second one doesnt have dao object set. As you are using the bean name of the service bean declared in your security config, you are getting userDao as null on debug.

Either comment the explicit bean definition in security xml, use ref="customUSerDetailsService" directly as @service annotation already added a bean with this name in spring context.

i.e. comment/remove this line in your security config and every thing should work.

```
<beans:bean class="com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.service.CustomUserDetailsService" id="customUserDetailsService"></beans:bean>
```

*When you annotate a bean with @component/@service spring adds a bean with name equals to short classname(first letter lower case), so bean with name "customUserDetailsService" already exists, defining it explicitly in xml is overriding it.*

Or declare all the bean definitions (including there dependencies) explicitly it xml config

Comment: wel.. yes i added a bean at the security xml.

Comment: so now there are two service beans, one autowired properly but not getting used and the other one in xml not getting populated with userDao. try using the service bean name in ref without declaring service bean in xml

Comment: im sorry but how do i do that? im still getting used to terms and concepts with spring.

Comment: i finally undesrtood what you are saying(kinda slow..) what I'm getting complicated it the authentication-manager because the authentication-provider has the refernce to the bean service of cutomUserDetailService but even when your trying to make it simple for me i just can't get to make the ref correct. could you help me one last time?  How do i put the re to the service bean customUserDetailsService from my authentication-manager.

Comment: just comment the explicit bean declaration for CustomUserDetailsService

Answer (score 1):

Add the dao package to the component scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.carloscortina.paidosSimple, com.carloscortina.paidosSimple.dao" />
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work.. the value of userDao keeps beign null

Comment: thats also my problem it shows no error or exceptions. I just know its null because i use the debug of Spring Tool Suite and add a breakline, and it says that the value is null.